# Does not show the output on emulator

Tags: android

I have written the following small bit of program but when I execute this program then it shows the error. I have mentioned the error the program. 
Please, any one could check and guide me what and where is the mistake. Thanks in advance. I need your great help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener{
    private boolean accelerometer = false;  // boolean variable to turn accelerometer if button clicked  
    private Landing landing;                //variable of Landing class to specify game area

    private  ButtonViews btnView = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

        btnView = new ButtonViews();
      //  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  // It won't display the heading with title
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// to get the content properties to be viewed on the screen once running
//        landing = (Landing)findViewById(R.id.Landing);

        // To control the accelerometer 
    /*  SensorManager sensorManager=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        */




        //Button Click listener for restart the game
        btnView.btnRestart.setOnClickListener(this);
      /*  btnView.btnExit.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnView.tilt.setOnClickListener(this);*/




}
class ButtonViews 
{
    public final Button btnRestart;             //button to restart the game again 
    private final Button btnExit;                   // button to exit the game 
    private final Button btnLeft;                   // button to move the space craft right side turn left thruster
    private final Button btnRight;              // button to move the space craft left side turn right thruster
    private final Button btnUp;                 // button to move the space craft up side turn main flame thruster
    private final Button tilt;                  // button to activate accelerometer feature in the contorl

    public ButtonViews(){
        btnRestart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        btnExit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        btnRight = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
        btnLeft = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
        btnUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUp);
        tilt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.action_Accelerometer);
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}



10-07 20:18:02.908: D/dalvikvm(1805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 51K, 9% free 7990K/8707K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
            10-07 20:18:02.916: I/dalvikvm-heap(1805): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.206MB for 947964-byte allocation
            10-07 20:18:02.932: D/dalvikvm(1805): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 8916K/9671K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 16ms
            10-07 20:18:02.992: D/dalvikvm(1805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 18K, 6% free 9113K/9671K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
            10-07 20:18:02.996: I/dalvikvm-heap(1805): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.770MB for 1440012-byte allocation
            10-07 20:18:03.012: D/dalvikvm(1805): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 10518K/11079K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 15ms
            10-07 20:18:03.068: D/dalvikvm(1805): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 11035K/11719K, paused 4ms, total 5ms
            10-07 20:18:03.096: D/AndroidRuntime(1805): Shutting down VM
            10-07 20:18:03.096: W/dalvikvm(1805): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa625d288)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.likhit.spacelanding/com.likhit.spacelanding.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.likhit.spacelanding.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            10-07 20:18:03.100: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     ... 11 more
            10-07 20:23:23.544: D/dalvikvm(1869): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 9% free 7990K/8707K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
            10-07 20:23:23.544: I/dalvikvm-heap(1869): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.206MB for 947964-byte allocation
            10-07 20:23:23.636: D/dalvikvm(1869): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 8916K/9671K, paused 68ms+1ms, total 90ms
            10-07 20:23:23.704: D/dalvikvm(1869): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 18K, 6% free 9113K/9671K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
            10-07 20:23:23.704: I/dalvikvm-heap(1869): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.770MB for 1440012-byte allocation
            10-07 20:23:23.720: D/dalvikvm(1869): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 10518K/11079K, paused 11ms+1ms, total 15ms
            10-07 20:23:23.788: D/dalvikvm(1869): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 11035K/11719K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
            10-07 20:23:23.800: D/AndroidRuntime(1869): Shutting down VM
            10-07 20:23:23.808: W/dalvikvm(1869): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa625d288)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.likhit.spacelanding/com.likhit.spacelanding.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at com.likhit.spacelanding.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:49)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            10-07 20:23:23.812: E/AndroidRuntime(1869):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: call "btnView = new ButtonViews();" after setContentView in onCreate because there is no view existence when you create ButtonViews object

Comment: `NullPointerException` on line 49. I imagine this is when you try to assign a listener to a button you have not correctly instantiated (see Tauqir's answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
btnView = new ButtonViews();
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

With

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
btnView = new ButtonViews();
```